# Build problems, using macports libs with GHC

Tags: haskell, osx-snow-leopard, macports, ghc

I'm trying to follow a [tutorial](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/tutorial/DiagramsTutorial.html) for the Diagrams library for haskell.

I've installed Cairo and gtk2hs with macports.

But when I try to run the tutorial examples, I get the following error:

```
$ ghc --make diagramsTutorial.lhs
Linking diagramsTutorial ...
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libatk-1.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
.. etc...
```

I'm using OS X 10.6.8, core i5 macbook pro.

**EDIT** I have just found that I'm using the 32bit haskell platform, which may be part of the problem. However I can't install the 64 bit version (it has an unspecified error during install). I can't find the uninstaller. According to [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Mac_OS_X), I should find an uninstaller at `/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Tools/Uninstaller` but there is nothing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Macports libraries are 64-bit only.  You can check with `lipo -info /opt/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.dylib`  If this is the case, you should reinstall them using the +universal variant, which will allow for linking both 32bit and 64bit code.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much it.